# Aviso de edição pendente ainda em Inglês

Tags: debate, internacionalização

Ontem estava num computador onde não queria fazer log-in e editei uma pergunta como um visitante anónimo e deparei-me com isto (que é o mesmo que os membros com menos de 1K vêem imagino).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Texto em Inglês:

> This edit will be visible only to you untill its per reviewed.

Sugestão de tradução:

> Esta edição só será visivel para sí até ser analizada por pela comunidade.

Outras sugestões são benvindas também.